# Range date filter in Datatables with Vue 3

Tags: javascript, datatables, vuejs3

I have used Datatables before as a JS library I would load to an HTML page, but now I am using it with Vue, and the previous method to apply a date range filter does not work, since I am not able to call the extended search function as the provided example:

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min = minDate.val();
        var max = maxDate.val();
        var date = new Date( data[4] );
 
        if (
            ( min === null && max === null ) ||
            ( min === null && date <= max ) ||
            ( min <= date   && max === null ) ||
            ( min <= date   && date <= max )
        ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

I have a button to call to a search function and tried a few naive things like:

```
let dt
const table = ref(null)

function search () {
  dt = table.value.dt()
  dt.search('string').draw
}
```

But the above limits the search/filter to the provided string and won't give the option to apply a function when it is being called.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution but at the end came out with something to mimic the filtering behaviour, if someone knows how to use the search plugin in Vue, please share your answer, so just in case somebody needs a solution for this one, I got the below:

Using composition API

```js
let dt
const table = ref(null)

// Button search click action
function searchDate() {
  dt = table.value.dt()

  let min = dayjs($('#to').val())
  let max = dayjs($('#from').val())

  let o = dt.data()

  let filtered = o.filter(o => {
    // calldate is the name of the column with the date type
    let cDate = dayjs(o.calldate)
    if (!min.isValid() || !max.isValid()) {
      return true
    }

    if (cDate.isValid()) {
      if (min.isBefore(cDate) && cDate.isBefore(max)) {
        return true
      }
    }
  })
  
  // Clear table and add filtered data
  dt.clear().rows.add(filtered).draw()  
}

// Reset clear button action, reloads data via AJAX call
function clearData () {
  dt = table.value.dt()
  dt.ajax.url(URL.GET_API).load()
  dt.search('').draw()
}

onMounted(() => {
  // Reload datatable data via AJAX call on datepicker input change
  $('input').on('change', function(){
    dt = table.value.dt()
    dt.ajax.url(URL.GET_API).load()
  })
})
```

This use dayJS library and JQuery for easy dom manipulation